# mismatch in formal parameter list: unable to resolve function overload

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors

So, writing my first program!  Any hints about the errors above will be appreciate!! :)
I'm getting mismatch formal parameter list and unable to resolve function overload.

many many thanks,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "COMPFUN.H"
using namespace std;

int main()


{
    double futureValue = 0.0;
    double presentValue = 0.0;
    double interestRate = 0.0;


    cout << "Please enter Present Value: ";
    cin >> presentValue;
    cout << "Please enter rate: ";
    cin >> interestRate;


futureValue = ( presentValue * 1 + interestRate / 1200.0 , 36) << endl;

    cout << "Future value is: " << futureValue << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect the

```
futureValue = ( presentValue * 1 + interestRate / 1200.0 , 36) << endl;
```

`endl` to do at the end of this line? Do you want to shift the result by `endl` bits? Do you want a `\n` appended to `futureValue` and have it flushed afterwards?

Comment: I was hoping to calculate the future value?  I'm going by my book (i should say trying to go by my book). um, endl i was hoping end the program, but keep the line displayed?

Comment: @Eric022584 no, `endl` simply prints a new line. It doesn't make sense for it to be there.

Comment: Running now, but future value is only = 36.  What's wrong with my formula futureValue = ( presentValue * 1 + interestRate / 1200.0 ,36);  I want it to be future value equals present value * (1 + rate)^n.

Comment: @Eric022584 why do you have `, 36` at the end? That's why it's evaluation to 36, that's how `operator,` works.

Comment: Well, starting rate is 1000.  the rate is 1200 amd 36 is for the time (3 years). @Luchian Grigore

Comment: @Eric022584 I suggest you learn C++ from a book, that's not at all how it works. The `, 36` doesn't make sense, not even mathematically. What are you expecting there? Multiplication? Division?

Comment: I guess the power function...that im trying to figure out